# Mustache js or php?

Tags: php, mustache, sonic

I have a controller and view file, from controller I am setting the data array for view, in the view file I am creating an instance of Mustache.php class and render the template of view.

In the second scenario: from controller I am setting the data array for view, and from view file I am calling Mustache.js to render a template.

Please let me know which is Ideal approach to do the same?

I am using PHP sonic framework(MVC)

Comment: Both of them are OK. If you use PHP, you won't deal php-js conversion. Php mustache instance keeps you from conversion

Comment: @cubuzoa thanks...and what about MVC protocols

Comment: What do you mean with MVC protocols? there is nothing wrong with that

Comment: @cubuzoa manipulate all data in controller/ model and just display in view....here I am creating an instance of mustache in view itself

Comment: mustache is logicless template. You need to develop your data structure on controller and assign it to view. That's right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of them are OK. If you use PHP, you won't deal php-js conversion. Php mustache instance keeps you from conversion.

**Note:**
A note for your MVC usage:

Mustache is logicless template. This means you need to prepare your data structure in controller and pass it to the view. Do not use filtering, conditioning, controlling structures on your view.

Answer (score 0):

I think JS is the best option. Imagine that you need to change DOM using these data variables you passed from your controller in the future. If you have it on JS stack it should be easier than if you have it on PHP stack.

Comment: how? Please elaborate your answer.